# Looking for public JSON enabled WCF web services 

Tags: wcf, json, service

... for testing a consumer application.

If you know of any, please let me have the URLs -- I am looking for unprotected services unless you can give me the uid & pwd for protected ones.

Thanks.

Comment: If they are JSON enabled why do you care what language they are written in? Why WCF?

Comment: @Darin: as I understand, web services can be *.asmx (ASP.NET) or *.svc (WCF) or *.wso (open source framework). *.asmx cannot be JSON enabled. *.wso can be (and I have tested these) but I have not found an *.svc JSON enabled service - I need to test these.

Comment: no, a web service could be written in almost any language you can imagine: Python, Java, Ruby, PHP, ... Also .asmx can be JSON enabled. Suffice to decorate the service class with the `[ScriptService]` attribute.

Comment: @Darin: .asmx can be JSON enabled? New to me - can you provide some links for further research, please? I am still looking for a *.svc web service that is JSON enabled; thanks.

Comment: sure, here's a good blog post about JSON enabled ASMX service: http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/12/17/calling-asp-net-web-service-asmx-from-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The following do provide (public) JSON services:
Flickr: 
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

GeoNames:
http://www.geonames.org/maps/json-googlemaps-example.html

BTW. A good way to learn is to use the fiddler tool to see what traffic is going back and forth while talking JSON.