# Web Service: XML & JSON Serialization enabled

Tags: xml, json, service

Following on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524219/looking-for-public-json-enabled-wcf-web-services) I have now enabled my ASP.NET web service to return XML or JSON serialization by resorting to different method names - this creates duplication.

Is there a way to have the consumer application 'specify something' so that the service returns XML or JSON without the service duplicating the method?

Also, how is [this](http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso/?op=AllPlayerNames) configured? I'd like my web service to allow the JSON option & to list the JSON description: Note it only lists one method & two ways of invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest

You can use the "Format" parameter to specify the serialization.